# How to update ROOM Database on information received on LiveData.observe?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-livedata

> I have this problem in two key places throughout my code, and can't solve it. I have the following problem: I want to retrieve information from by database and update it all at the same time. I have a room database with an ordinary repository and viewmodel. And my code is this:

```
daysViewModel.getStopsBiggerThan(day).observe(this, new Observer<List<DayActivity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<DayActivity> dayActivities) {
                Log.d("stop_please_in_bigger", dayActivities.toString());
                if (sort == 1) {
                    for (DayActivity stop : dayActivities) {
                        DayActivity new_stop = new DayActivity(stop.getTitle_Day(), stop.getLocation_Day(), stop.getStars_Day(),
                                stop.getOpening_hours_1_Day(), stop.getOpening_hours_2_Day(), stop.getOpening_hours_3_Day(),
                                stop.getNotas_Day(), stop.getDay_Day() - 1, stop.getStarttime_Day(),
                                stop.getEndtime_Day(), stop.getOrder_Day());
                        new_stop.setId_Day(stop.getId_Day());
                        daysViewModel.update(new_stop);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

> Firstly, I have tried to use a simple list instead of a LiveData but then it just returned a null object. I have also tried to include a variable to act like a switch "sort" and it didin't work.
>
> As most of you probably have understood by now, the problem is that by changing the database query information on an onChanged void, I am feeding a vicious loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Turns out this was a stupid question... Just try and define a variable and play around with it!